# I'm trying to explode a string in python pandas by a delimiter but it isn't working

Tags: python, pandas-explode

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': 1 , 2],
                  'artist': ['Elton John', 'Biffy Clyro'],
                  'song': ['Rocket Man', 'Bubbles']
                  'id': ['B12, U6, Z5', 'H91, D293, P292']})
```

I need to explode these so that it looks like this:

| index | artist | song | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Elton John | Rocket Man | B12 |
| 1 | Elton John | Rocket Man | U6 |
| 1 | Elton John | Rocket Man | Z5 |
| 2 | Biffy Clyro | Bubbles | H91 |
| 2 | Biffy Clyro | Bubbles | D293 |
| 2 | Biffy Clyro | Bubbles | P292 |

I ran this code in line with [this question I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495847/pandas-to-create-new-rows-from-a-cell-that-has-multiple-values-in-python):

```
df['id'] = df['id'].str.split(", ")
df.explode('id')
```

But alas! It returned the same as before but with the spaces in the id column removed, so it looked like this:

| index | artist | song | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Elton John | Rocket Man | B12,U6,Z5 |
| 2 | Biffy Clyro | Bubbles | H91,D293,P292 |

If I tack the second line of code onto the first as I saw suggested in another thread it just gives me one id.

````
```
df['id'] = df['id'].str.split(", ").explode('id')
```
````

| index | artist | song | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Elton John | Rocket Man | B12 |
| 2 | Biffy Clyro | Bubbles | H91 |

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is working fine, but make sure to catch the output of `df.explode('id')`